Sony IMX421 Eval board with IMX422 Sensor - produces odd repeating patterns instead of true images
I am working on an application that involves use of a Sony IMX422 CMOS image sensor - namely writing VHDL code to act as a receiver interface to the sensor over an SLVS bus.  the setup involves a Framos IMX421 evaluation board that includes the relevant power supplies (digital, analogue, system and interface) to work with the camera and some other logic.  The sensor is removable by unscrewing part of the plate and it simply drops out.  This is to allow this board to be used with different sensors within the same basic family.
The FPGA dev kit I am using is a SoCKit board from Terasic, that includes a Cyclone V device.  There is an HSMC connector provided for external connections to other boards.  The Framos board only has a X connector, so we have designed and had manufactured a "bridge board" to connect the 2.  This also has a switching regulator on it to supply the required 5V to the Framos board, which then uses this to generate the other voltages required which are:
3.3V system
3.3V Analogue
1.2V digital
1.8V interface
Basically the issue I am having is this - the camera includes a pattern generator feature.  When I set this up and then let the system run, I receive back correct patterns.  I can verify this by the values that come back but also that I also receive correct Start and End of Line Valid codes at the FPGA as well as the Horizontal Blanking values (01h when using 8-bit depth).  However when I take the camera out of pattern generator mode, the image data is garbage.  What is more odd is that everything else is still correct - I get back the correct sync codes, and blanking codes - but the image data itself is nonsense.  I have verified this by doing the following:
Covering image sensor and monitoring the signals coming over the SLVS lanes using appropriate high speed scope/diff probe AND observing SLVS data captured by FPGA using signaltap
uncovering image sensor, shining a light into the camera and monitoring the same as before
Turning on pattern generator and performing same test as before
In each scenario, the data coming across the data lanes matches what we receive at the FPGA end (perhaps a redundant test, as we could see the sync codes being received in signaltap correctly but worth verifying).
The image data received when the camera is in non-pattern mode is of this basic format:

This shows Image data as saved in RAM and then sent to P.C. over stdio.  I get 2 or 3 lines of value 0Fh (15d), and then multiple lines that mostly only sit at 2 extremes of 01h and FEh.
The Values 255, 0, 0, 157 are simply the SAV sync codes coming in (x8 as 8 lanes used) to confirm correct reception of image.
The picture below shows this same type of data coming through on the FPGA receiver firmware (probed by signaltap)

..And this next picture shows an image pulled off of the RAM; as you can see, it repeats:

We also have a Framos(?) CUEboard - an evaluation board for testing that the camera is working.  I have set this up multiple times with the Camera board itself and everything works fine.
The obvious things to test for were:
signal integrity of master clock
power integrity (especially of analogue power supply on the Framos Camera board)
register settings
We have an excel spreadsheet provided by Sony/Framos at some point that details all of the other registers you have to program. I have followed this to the letter and it has made no difference.  I have even looked through the setup files for the CUEBoard, since it has always worked fine with the camera. These consist of .icf and .ism files - and one of these contains i2c register settings.  So, ensuring my setup with the sockit was expecting the same camera mode as that used by the Cue board (e.g. 8-bit, 239 fps etc) I used these register settings, and have also compared them to those in the spreadsheet.  They are mostly identical, and do not cause the camera to work either.
Further images here confirm signal integrity of the sensor master clock:

The above screenshot shows how the sensor master clock, generated from an oscillator on the Framos camera board, degrades somewhat through an OR gate on the board that also doubles as a level translator.  However, if you refer to the next picture, below, you will see that this same degradation occurs with the clock when the CUEboard is being used, yet the CUEBoard functions correctly:

I do not have screenshots to hand but a colleague and I also checked the power integrity of the 3.3V analogue supply (since the digital side is ok we reckon that the analogue side of the sensor is somehow at fault).  If anything the analogue supply seemed slightly cleaner when generated via the SoCKit's and custom bridge board's 5V than when supplied via the CUEBoard.
I have seen this question here which I think might be related:
CMOS image sensor does not produce a picture, only vertical green/pink lines
I am at a total loss at this point as to what is causing the issue.
Is there a common issue with Sony imx CMOS sensors that causes this to occur?  Does anybody reckon it is an issue with sensor settings?  (Although I have already gone over these multiple times; and as I said before; these match those used with the CUEboard setup).

The fix turned out to be simpler than expected.
The Pattern Generator enable register has 3 programmable bits.
Bit 2 Bit 1 Bit 0
PG clock enable PG background data PG on/off
Apparently when reset, the register is set to 0x06, enabling the PG clock and background data and switching the PG off. At some point when making my software I must have thought "I should disable the PG clock". Looking at the app note (I can't share it here obviously) there is no implication that it would do any harm to have this disabled. I quote "Set to '1h' when using Pattern Generator". However, by fluke I tried setting things up without writing to this register at all, and the system worked. Very soon discovered it was because the PG clock was enabled. For some reason having this disabled when in image mode causes the camera to output total garbage. I can only think that the clocking for the analogue side of the chip is somehow related to this PG clock also? Not sure. But the main thing is, it is working.

This was the one register I never really checked, as I thought that with the PG off, any other settings shouldn't affect anything in image mode.
